# How can we specify custom path to .Files.Get when creating ConfigMap with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am creating a config map as below

`kubectl create configmap testconfigmap --from-file=testkey=/var/opt/testfile.txt`

As I am using helm charts, I would like to create the config map using YAML file instead of running kubectl.
I went through [Kubernetes - How to define ConfigMap built using a file in a yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429486/kubernetes-how-to-define-configmap-built-using-a-file-in-a-yaml) and we can use `.Files.Get` to access the files.
But then testfile.txt needs to be a part of helm. I would like to have something like

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: testconfigmap
data:
  fromfile: |-
{{ .Files.Get "/var/opt/testfile.txt" | indent 4 }}
```

It works when "testfile.txt" is under the main helm directory. So, `{{ .Files.Get "testfile.txt" | indent 4 }}` works but `{{ .Files.Get "/var/opt/testfile.txt" | indent 4 }}` doesn't. With custom path, the value for the ConfigMap is empty.

Is is possible to place the file at a custom path outside the helm folder, so I can define my path in Values.yaml and read it in my ConfigMap yaml ?

Comment: *Is is possible to place the file at a custom path outside the helm folder* no, because [helm considers that a security risk](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/)

Answer (score 5):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As [mdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel) has already stated in his comment:

> *Is is possible to place the file at a custom path outside the helm
> folder* no, because [helm considers that a security risk](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) – mdaniel 2
> days ago

You can also compare it with [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3276) feature request on **GitHub** where you can find very similar requirement described in short e.g. in [this comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3276#issuecomment-353675624):

> I have this exact need. My chart publishes a secret read from file at
> /keybase. This file is deliberately not in the chart.
>
> I believe files for .Files.Get should not be assumed to be inside the
> chart ...

One interesting [comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3276#issuecomment-353718344):

> lenalebt commented on Dec 23, 2017 I am quite sure .`Files.Get` not
> being able to access the file system arbitrarily is a security
> feature, so I don't think the current behaviour is wrong - it just
> does not fulfill all use cases.

This issue was created quite long time ago (Dec 19, 2017) but has been recently reopened. There are even [some specific proposals on how it could be handled](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3276#issuecomment-607952569):

> titou10titou10 commented on Apr 2 @misberner can you confirm that
> using--include-dir =will allow us to use
> .Files.Glob().AsConfig(), and so create a ConfigMap with one
> entry in the CM per file in?
>
> @misberner misberner commented on Apr 2 Yeah that's the idea. An open
> question from my point of view is whether an --include-dir with a
> specified  introduces an overlay, or shadows everything under
> / from previous args and from the bundle itself. I'm not super
> opinionated on that one but would prefer the former.

The most recent comments give some hope that this feature might become available in future releases of helm.

Answer (score 1):

As [mdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel) and [mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11714114/mario) already mentioned, for now this is not possible, as it's considered a security risk.

But actually there ***is*** a workaround.
You can use Helm templating to parse your property file and load it into a ConfigMap.

```
# create the following ConfigMap in your Chart
# this is just a simple prototype
# it requires strict key=value syntax in your property file (no empty strings etc.)
# but it shows the idea - improve the syntax, if needed
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example
data:
  {{- if .Values.example.map }}
  {{- range $line := splitList "\n" .Values.example.map }}
  {{- $words := splitList "=" $line }}
  {{- $key := index $words 0 | trim }}
  {{- $value := rest $words | join "=" | trim }}
  {{ $key }}: "{{ $value }}"
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And after that you may load your properties file into this ConfigMap.

```
helm install mychart --set-file example.map="/test/my.properties"
```

Of course it is safe to use ONLY if you fully control the input, i. e. how each and every line of your property file is populated.